# Recebimento de HEX Via TCP

Tags: c#

Preciso converter uma string que foi convertida para HEX e enviada via TCP para string.

Tentei das 2 formas abaixo e só recebo string ilegiveis :

```
public async void HandleConnections(TcpClient client)
{
  using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
  {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
    {

    returndata = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

    }

  }

}

public async void HandleConnections(TcpClient client)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

    string returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (bytes);

    Console.WriteLine (returndata);
}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar um exemplo da string original e da string convertida para HEX?

Comment: Este dispositivo que está enviando é um rastreador GPS, em contato com o fabricante o máximo que me informaram é que é enviado em formato HEX. Estou recebendo uma string inelegível.

Comment: Estou recebendo esta sequencia de bytes 78-78-0D-01-03-56-80-32-10-10-31-86-00-15-67-B2-0D-0A

Comment: HEX é apenas uma representação. Você sempre vai receber uma sequencia de bytes. Se ele enviasse os bytes representando caracteres HEX deveria enviar apenas bytes com valores de 60 a 71 (x30 a x39) e 101 a 106 (x41 a x46) porque isso, convertido, representaria os caracteres possíveis do HEX. Pela sequencia que você colocou está estranho pq caracteres 00 até 32 (x00 a x20) são caracteres de controle do ASCII e não são visíveis. Tente obter mais informações com o fabricante.